# Is any way to Openshift respect Docker ENV variables

Tags: docker, openshift, docker-container, trust

I have been working with Docker Notary to help verify the trust of the images that we use, but now I want to use this feature inside Openshift. In theory, Openshift uses the Docker Client so if you setup the environment variable DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 it supposes that just use images from trusted sources.
I setup the variable trough /etc/environment or even with export but no luck at all.
Does anyone know if this is possible?  Doesn't Openshift respect the custom settings from the Docker Client?
Thanks in advance for the help